# Getting error while calling webservice using node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js

can you please tell me how to call json webservice and get output ?I need some steps how to do that task.
I am just started using node.js.
I create a js file using command promt i run that file

```
var request = require("request");
request.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json", function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err) {
        var resultsObj = JSON.parse(body);
        //Just an example of how to access properties:
        console.log(resultsObj.MRData);
    }
});


   Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\nksharma.Q3TECH>cd..

C:\Documents and Settings>cd..

C:\>cd node

C:\node>npm install request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
request@2.29.0 node_modules\request
├── forever-agent@0.5.0
├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
├── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
├── qs@0.6.6
├── mime@1.2.11
├── node-uuid@1.4.1
├── tough-cookie@0.9.15 (punycode@1.2.3)
├── hawk@1.0.0 (cryptiles@0.2.2, sntp@0.2.4, boom@0.4.2, hoek@0.9.1)
├── http-signature@0.10.0 (assert-plus@0.1.2, asn1@0.1.11, ctype@0.5.2)
└── form-data@0.1.2 (async@0.2.9, combined-stream@0.0.4)

C:\node>node b.js
{ xmlns: 'http://ergast.com/mrd/1.2',
  series: 'f1',
  url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json',
  limit: '30',
  offset: '0',
  total: '22',
  RaceTable: { season: '2013', round: '19', Races: [ [Object] ] } }

C:\node>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not install the request module, but you are trying to use it. Navigate to your project folder in your console and install the request module with:

```
npm install request
```

Then try again, the Cannot find module error should be gone.

Comment: still i am facing one problem not getting result

Comment: Looks good to me. What you see is the result object you are logging with your console.log(resultsObj.MRData). ;)

Comment: how to get value in that

Comment: @user2648752 it's you again! You really want your army of bored programmers to help you with every single tiny step? come on man. Learn something instead of asking everyone for help.